# Stock split information from Alphavantage API

Tags: alpha-vantage

I'm trying to build a simple portfolio tracker application using Alphavantage API. In order to achieve this, I need to know what stock splits have occurred so I can adjust how many shares the user owns. Does Alphavantage give me a way to see data on stock splits (when the split occurred, and the ratio - 2 way , 4 way, etc?).